# SQL select after where clause

Tags: sql-server, select, join

Here is the setup:

```
Table 1: table_1
column_id
column_12
column_13
column_14

Table 2: table_2
column_id
column_21
column_22
```

Select statement:

```
DECLARE @Variable 
INT SET @Variable = 300

SELECT b.column_id, 
        b.column_12, 
        SUM(b.column_13) OVER (PARTITION BY b.column_id ORDER BY b.column_12) AS sum_column_13, 
        @Variable / nullif(SUM(b.column_13) OVER (PARTITION BY b.column_id ORDER BY b.column_12),0) AS divide_var, 
        (b.column_13*100) / nullif(b.column_14,0) AS divide_column_3 
FROM dbo.table_1 b 
WHERE b.column_12 IN ('AM','AJ','A-M','A-J','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q');
```

This works great, all the formulas are working and the correct results are shown.
`b.column_id` is retrieved
`b.column_12` is retrieved
`sum_column_13` is equal to the sum of all the `column_13` values (partitioned by `column_id`)
`divide_var` is equal to a variable dived by `sum_column_13`
`divide_column_13` is equal to `column_13` divided by `column_14`

Now however I am trying to retrieve the `@Variable` from `table_2`, instead of it being static.

Both tables have a `column_id`, which could link them together. However this value is not unique.
The actual number for `@Variable` should come from `table_2`; by summing all the values of `column_21` for each column_id.(Something similar sum_column_13)

I can make both things work separately, but when I try to combine them (with a `JOIN`, or an extra `SELECT` class) everything goes wild. For example when using the `JOIN` statement, the `WHERE` class is solely applied to the `JOIN` statement and not to the `SELECT` statement. How I imagine it should go is to use the `column_id` results from the current `SELECT`, then use this to retrieve the required data from `table_2`.

I understand my explanation is not very clear. So [here is an SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3583/1).
As you can see the variable right now comes from adding up the two values in `table_2`. 
Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Comment: "when using the JOIN statement, the WHERE class is solely applied to the JOIN statement and not to the SELECT statement" --- What do you mean by this

Comment: The WHERE clause seems only to be applied to the JOIN statement. So it tries to do a JOIN, WHERE those values apply. (At least from looking at my results). However it should apply this WHERE clause to the select statement to get the proper column_id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code, I've not made use of variable instead I'm using the sum of columns directly, also I've made use of CTE:

```
with tbl_2(col_id, col_sum) as
( select col_id, sum(column_21) col_sum from tbl_2 group by col_id)
SELECT b.column_id, 
        b.column_12, 
        SUM(b.column_13) OVER (PARTITION BY b.column_id ORDER BY b.column_12) AS sum_column_13, 
        col_sum / nullif(SUM(b.column_13) OVER (PARTITION BY b.column_id ORDER BY b.column_12),0) AS divide_var, 
        (b.column_13*100) / nullif(b.column_14,0) AS divide_column_3 
FROM dbo.table_1 b 
join tbl_2 on b.col_id=tbl_2.col_id
WHERE b.column_12 IN ('AM','AJ','A-M','A-J','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q');
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not getting the results what I am hoping for.. But I also noticed a mistake in my question. Instead of the sum of column_21 and column_22, I am actually looking for the sum of all the values of column_21 based on a column_id  (similar to sum_column_13)

Comment: In that case I've edited my answer, please try again and let me know.

Comment: I am going to check it out. I have included a SQLFiddle, which might help explain myself a bit better. Thanks for your help!